# Play Framework/Scala getting specific files

Tags: scala, playframework

I have two inputs image and music.
With image i have not problems handling it as

```
val imageFile = request.body.file("imageFile").get.ref.file
```

however, musicFile can be multiple and i couldn't find a way to get them with `request.body.file("musicFile")`
I can get them as request.body.files but this also return the image file now the problem how i am gonna identify them.?
I am using playframework 2.1.1 with Scala

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my way  : you can get all files by `request.body.files`
and then check the files =>file

```
file.key.equals("musicFile")
```